# must implement EITHER interface A OR interface B (exactly one)

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IOpportunity
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
    ILocation Location { get; }
}

public interface ILocation : IHierarchicalEntity 
{ 
    int OpptyCount { get; }
}

public interface IHierarchicalEntity 
{ 
    string SID { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

However, I want the ILocation object to also implement ONE of these interfaces:

```
public interface IHierarchicalEntityWithParentNames : IHierarchicalEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the lowest level that this heirarchy goes (0 for a flat hierarchy, 1 for a two-level etc.)
    /// </summary>
    int LeafLevel { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the name of the Segment for the given level (0 for a root node, n for leaf node, where n = LeafLevel)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="level"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    string GetNameForLevel(int level);
}


public interface IHierarchicalEntityWithParentIds : IHierarchicalEntity
{
    IHierarchicalEntityWithParentIds ParentEntity { get; }
    string ParentSID { get; }
}
```

Due to the nature of the code I am writing, I cannot combine these interfaces into one interface that has some sort of `GetParent` method

In the code that consumes these interfaces, I have two classes - one that consumes the ILocation object if it is an `IHierarchicalEntityWithParentNames` and another if it is an `IHierarchicalEntityWithParentIds`

How would I lay out the interfaces (perhaps I have to have some abstract classes) to support having this "one or the other" design?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  You either explicitly implement an interface, or you don't.  What you're describing is effectively "either method A *or* method B will exist," but that's not a concept that exists in C# (or any other language that I'm aware of!).

The closest you'll be able to get would be to throw an exception in the code that consumes your interface if the class doesn't also implement one of the other two interfaces.

Alternatively, I imagine you could have a base class whose constructor will throw an exception if it doesn't also implement one or other of the interfaces.  This would give you an earlier check, but it's still a runtime check and, personally, I think it's a horrible idea.

Comment: +1 for confirming what I already knew, but still not a great solution (as you stated yourself)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are over-constraining the true problem. This is very similar to an issue I encountered in my game engine, where coordinates on a hex grid can be either in the canonical reference frame (axes at 120 degress, convenient for most internal game functions) or in the rectangular  (user) reference frame with axes at 90 degrees (convenient for most user-visiable game functions).

I addressed this by buidlng a single class Coords that explicitly implements both interfaces ICoordsCanon and ICoordsUser. The actual coordinates are lazily stored and evaluated with an automated conversion like this:

```
protected static IntMatrix2D MatrixUserToCanon;
protected IntVector2D VectorCanon {
  get { return ! isCanonNull ? _vectorCanon 
                             : VectorUser * MatrixUserToCanon; }
  set { _vectorCanon = value;  isUserNull = true; }
} IntVector2D _vectorCanon;
bool isCanonNull;

protected static IntMatrix2D MatrixCanonToUser;
protected IntVector2D VectorUser {
  get { return ! isUserNull  ? _vectorUser 
                             : VectorCanon * MatrixCanonToUser; }
  set { _vectorUser  = value;  isCanonNull = true; }
} IntVector2D _vectorUser;
bool isUserNull;
```

The constructor for Coords is private, with public static functions NewUserCoords(...) and NewCanonCoords(...) defined.

Alhough the implementation is not truly either ... or ..., it APPEARS to be implemented so to the application. Most application usages either works with ICoordsCanon objects, or with ICoordsUser objects; the two methods ICoordsCanon.User() and ICoordsUser.Canon() exist for converting between the two as necessary.

By popular demand, here are the interface definitions and implementations.

```
  public interface ICoordsUser {
    int             X         { get; }
    int             Y         { get; }
    IntVector2D     Vector    { get; set; }
    ICoordsCanon    Canon     { get; }
    //ICoordsUser     Clone();
    string          ToString();
    int             Range(ICoordsUser coords);
    IEnumerable<NeighbourCoords> GetNeighbours(Hexside hexsides);
  }

  public partial class Coords {
    int           ICoordsUser.X          { get { return VectorUser.X; } }
    int           ICoordsUser.Y          { get { return VectorUser.Y; } }
    IntVector2D   ICoordsUser.Vector     { get { return VectorUser;   }
                                           set { VectorUser=value;    } }
    ICoordsCanon  ICoordsUser.Canon      { get { return this;         } } 
    //ICoordsUser   ICoordsUser.Clone()    { return NewUserCoords(VectorUser); }
    string        ICoordsUser.ToString() { return VectorUser.ToString(); }

    IEnumerable<NeighbourCoords> ICoordsUser.GetNeighbours(Hexside hexsides) { 
      return GetNeighbours(hexsides); 
    }
    int ICoordsUser.Range(ICoordsUser coords) { return Range(coords.Canon); }
  }
}
```

and

```
  public interface ICoordsCanon {
    int             X         { get; }
    int             Y         { get; }
    IntVector2D     Vector    { get; set; }
    ICoordsCustom   Custom    { get; }
    ICoordsUser     User      { get; }
    //ICoordsCanon    Clone();
    string          ToString();
    int             Range(ICoordsCanon coords);
    IEnumerable<NeighbourCoords> GetNeighbours(Hexside hexsides);
  }
  public partial class Coords {
    int             ICoordsCanon.X          { get { return VectorCanon.X; } }
    int             ICoordsCanon.Y          { get { return VectorCanon.Y; } }
    IntVector2D     ICoordsCanon.Vector     { get { return VectorCanon;   }
                                              set { VectorCanon=value;    } }
    ICoordsUser     ICoordsCanon.User       { get { return this; } }
    ICoordsCustom   ICoordsCanon.Custom     { get { return this; } }
    //ICoordsCanon    ICoordsCanon.Clone()    { return NewCanonCoords(this.VectorCanon); }
    string          ICoordsCanon.ToString() { return VectorCanon.ToString(); }

    IEnumerable<NeighbourCoords> ICoordsCanon.GetNeighbours(Hexside hexsides) { 
      return GetNeighbours(hexsides); 
    }
    int ICoordsCanon.Range(ICoordsCanon coords) { return Range(coords); }
  }
```

Note that I have not included the entire definition of class Coords, as that would simply be far too large a post. The entire implementation is availabel on CodePlex here: [HexGrid Utilities](http://hexgridutilities.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I like the direction you're going here - can you paste in your interface definitions?

Comment: I don't think this will work for me, because I want to keep the definitions separate (they may be convertible, but they don't need to be).  Also, I want the implementer to provide the implementation for ILocation, not me.

Comment: That sounds like the refactoring I am part way through right now. This was originally implemented specifically for hexGrids. I am now abstracting base class functionality only into abstract class Coords, with the Hex-grid specific code in the sub-class HexCoords. Then a new implemenation IsometricCoords will be built and tested. The refactoring is progressing smoothly, but will not be uploaded for a few days at least.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to enforce this at compile time.  I think you would have to make this a runtime check by using a base class that throws an exception if both interfaces are implemented.

However, that won't stop someone from bypassing your base class and implementing the interfaces themselves, and I know of no way to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Code Contracts. Post-condition. Smth like this

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(IOpportunity))]
public abstract class OpportunityContract : IOpportunity
{

    public ILocation Location
    {
        get { Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<ILocation>() is IHierarchicalEntityWithParentNames || Contract.Result<ILocation>() is IHierarchicalEntityWithParentIds); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this provides any compile-time checking - does it?